# Dynamic gauge chart with colors changing based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

II'm trying to create a dynamic gaugemeter where the colors change depending on a value in a cell. For now they are set to min max in the meter options itself, but I'm trying to find an apps script that will make the colors dynamic.

In this particular case the colors should change with the redFrom,  redTo, yellowFrom, yellowTo, greenFrom and greenTo values

I found several scripts and tried to modify them in a chance that I could get it to work, with no luck. (script is in the example file)

Is there anybody who can help me get this right? I have been trying to make this work for about a week now (example file is just created, original company file needs to stay internal)

I tried modifying the scripts that I found to work with my use case, I am close but don't seem to get it to work.

Ps. This is my first post, if i didn't set the post up correctly please let me know for future interaction,

thank you!

Comment: Can you share sample code?

Comment: Hi, yes i included the code

Comment: Are you able to actually add your sample code to your question and delete the answer you posted? Right now it looks like you are answering your own question with the code you provided.  Can you also explainw hat's not working with the code you provided? Just to confirm, are you trying to change the values where the existing gauge colors are applied or are you trying to change the actual colors that appear on the gaugemeter?

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateGaugeChart() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Gaugemeter");

  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet 'Gaugemeter' not found. Please make sure the sheet name is 
correct.");
    return;
  }

  // Get the values from the specified cells
  var minGauge = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var maxGauge = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var minRed = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var maxRed = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var minYellow = sheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var maxYellow = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var minGreen = sheet.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var maxGreen = sheet.getRange("I2").getValue();

  // Get the chart in the sheet (replace "Chart 1" with your actual chart name)
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var chart;
  if (charts.length > 0) {
    chart = charts[0]; // Assuming there's only one chart in the sheet
  } else {
    // Create a new chart if none exists
    chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asGaugeChart()
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:B1"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("D1:E1"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("F1:G1"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("H1:I1"))
  .setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0)
  .build();
  }

  // Modify the chart data and ranges
  var ranges = chart.getRanges();
  ranges[0].setMin(minGauge);
  ranges[0].setMax(maxGauge);
  ranges[1].setMin(minRed);
  ranges[1].setMax(maxRed);
  ranges[2].setMin(minYellow);
  ranges[2].setMax(maxYellow);
  ranges[3].setMin(minGreen);
  ranges[3].setMax(maxGreen);

  // Create a new chart with the modified ranges
  var newChart = 

      chart.modify().clearRanges().addRange(ranges[0]).addRange(ranges[1]).addRange(ranges[2]).addRange(ranges[3]).build();

  // Remove existing chart (if any) and add the new chart to the sheet
  if (charts.length > 0) {
  sheet.removeChart(charts[0]);
  }
  sheet.insertChart(newChart);
}
```